# Keyclock custom required action not showing up in UI

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to add a custom Keycloak required action to my Keycloak instance
So far I have been adding the following files

- `providers/pom.xml`
- `providers/invitation/pom.xml` (parent - child)
- `providers/invitation/src/main/java/it/rent/auth/requiredaction/InvitationRequiredAction.java` which implements `RequiredActionProvider`
- `providers/invitation/src/main/java/it/rent/auth/requiredaction/InvitationRequiredActionFactory.java` which implements `RequiredActionFactory`
- `providers/invitation/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.authentication.RequiredActionFactory` with the following content: `it.rent.auth.requiredaction.InvitationRequiredActionFactory`

The keycloak Docker file looks like

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build/providers

ENV MODULES="invitation"
RUN for module in $MODULES; do mkdir -p "/build/providers/$module"; done
COPY providers/pom.xml /build/providers/pom.xml
COPY providers/invitation/pom.xml /build/providers/invitation/pom.xml

RUN mvn -B clean

COPY providers /build/providers

RUN mvn -B package

FROM jboss/keycloak:4.8.2.Final
```

The build output seems promising as it says

```
[INFO]
[INFO] Providers .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.020 s]
[INFO] invitation ......................................... SUCCESS [  2.449 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyway after landing to the admin dashboard I am not able to see my required action in the required actions list.
[image: Screen]

What do I miss here?

Comment: Where do you put your builded files (jar?) after building it in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Evil_skunk to point this out, I forgot to copy my builded jar files to `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments`.

So I managed to fix this problem by adding the following line at the end ouf my Dockerfile

```
COPY --from=builder /build/providers/invitation/target/*.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
```